# Making a zombie's target range higher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am spawning a zombie via a command block using the following command:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"\"TomsZombie\"",CustomNameVisible:1,PersistenceRequired:1b,Invulnerable:1,Attributes:[{Name:generic.followRange,Base:80}]}
```

I've read that the Attributes section will change the distance a zombie will follow you, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-145656

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to find another solution to make it work as I want